# Last row id always return zero in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, ios4, xcode4.2

```
  NSString *strMQueryupdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into        Zpatient_info_image_note values ('%@','%@',NULL,'%@')",@"",autoNumberTextField.text,@""];

  NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];

Patient_info_image_note *patientImageData = (Patient_info_image_note *)   [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Patient_info_image_note" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

patientImageData.autonumber=autoNumberTextField.text;
patientImageData.patient_Info_Note_Image=@"";
patientImageData.noteDate=@"";
patientImageData.noteNumber=NULL;

[moc save:nil];
lastrowid=[[[[patientImageData objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString] intValue];

patientImageData=nil;
```

What is incorrect in this code?as a second option should i create another coulmn which saved integer starting from 0 and increment it by 1 and then save it to database so that next time i can retrieve the last incremented number by the count of array.

Answer (score 1):

if you print the value of `[[[patientImageData objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString]` you will get something like:

> x-coredata://3BB81DA1-4516-45A0-8895-7FD710C74247/LapTime/p61

trying to get its intValue will give you 0.

Comment: thanx for your response, is there any autoincremented column provided in core data which i can use?

Comment: No, there is not, however there is the objectID (it is unique), but wont help your case. What you can do is add a property of your own (an NSNumber). And then whenever you want, you can sort your data array using a sort descriptor on the key (your property) or get the maxValue (using aggregate functions `@max.id`).